# Are there any library for voice recognition on mobile (ios android)

Tags: android, ios, audio, speech-recognition

I want to implement some simple transcriber for deaf people, so I need a library for mobile (ios and android) that will help me to recognize the audio from the microphones and convert it into text.

I'm not concerned about the library autocorrecting words, because I want also random words or screams to be recognized.

Also I would love if it can work offline.

Comment: I'd recommend checking out PocketSphinx for Android: http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialandroid

Comment: Honestly, it wasn't more than a quick google search away. Literally the first listing when you search for "speech recognition android". I'd try a quick look before posting a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google does:

`public static SpeechRecognizer createSpeechRecognizer (Context context, ComponentName serviceComponent)`

There is a speech recognition class (literally [SpeechRecognizer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.html)) which can be used for that.

There are a few third party options which can be used for iOS. Given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16812399/how-to-use-speech-recognition-inside-the-ios-sdk) and also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18602483/apple-dictation-use-in-app/18602749#18602749).

Answer (score 1):

Android have already a API for this, take a look:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.html

The api can be used offline, but the user needs to download the offline speech recognition package.

In this topic, you will find more information:

[Java speech recognition API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034925/java-speech-recognition-api)